Linearly independent distributions on space of slowly increasing functions (example from Gelfand and Shilov)
Consider the space of so-called "slowly increasing" entire functions on $\mathbb{C}$. Such a function $f(z)$ is entire on $\mathbb{C}$ and obeys, for some $a > 0$ and for all $q \in \mathbb{N}$,
\begin{equation*}
|z|^q |f(z)| \le C_q e^{a |\text{Im}\,z|}.
\end{equation*}
This space of functions, and the linear functionals (i.e., "distributions") acting on it, are studied in Chapter 2 of the classical treatise by Gelfand and Shilov.
The authors give an interesting construction of analytic functionals stemming from the mappings $z \to e^{z^n}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Specifically, because $|e^{z^n}| = e^{|z|^n \cos(n \text{arg}\, z)}$, the $z$-plane is divided into $2n$ equal sectors, each subtending and angle of $\pi/n$, such that $|e^{z^n}|$ alternately increases in the sectors that are "ridges", and decreases in the sectors that are "valleys".
For each $k = 2, \dots , N$ we fix a contour $\Gamma_k$ in the complex plane that starts at $\infty$ in the first valley and ends at $\infty$ in the $k$th valley. Using these we form $n-1$ functionals,
\begin{equation*}
(F_k, f) := \int_{\Gamma_k} e^{z^n} f(z) dz,
\end{equation*}
which converge due the exponentially decaying nature of $|e^{z^n}|$ in the valleys.

Gelfand and Shilov claim without proof, and I would like to show, that the functionals $F_k$, $k = 1, \dots, n-1$ are linearly independent. This seems to require testing the $F_k$ against cleverly chosen test functions $f$, which is where I'm stuck. The main problem is that, we cannot use nontrivial compactly supported functions as our test functions, because they are not entire.

Gelfand and Shilov go on to use contour deformation and integration by parts to show that each $F_k$ satisfies the first order differential equation
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{dz} F_k = n \overline{z^{n-1}} F_k,
\end{equation*}
where the distributional derivative is defined by $(\tfrac{d}{dz} F_k, f) = (F_k, -\tfrac{d}{dz}f)$.
So, this construction brings about the interesting conclusion that a first order differential equation for a distribution on the slowly increasing functions may have any number of linearly independent solutions. This stands in contrast to the ODE theory for real-variable functions.
Edit: The Fourier transforms of the $F_k$, which are distributions acting on functions $\varphi(x) \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$, are given by
\begin{equation*}
\hat{F}_k = \int_{\Gamma_k} e^{z^n} e^{-i x z}dz.
\end{equation*}
Each of these is a solution to the differential equation of order $n-1$ given by
\begin{equation*}
n\big(\frac{d}{dx}\big)^{n-1} y(x) = -(-i)^n x y(x).
\end{equation*}
This provides intuition about why the $F_k$ should be linearly independent, and we are free to instead work on the Fourier transformed side. But I still have not been able to find a good way to handle the $\hat{F}_k$.
